# Terraform -- access resource which is created in the same main.tf file

Tags: terraform

I'm created a secret manager AWS resource and want to access it's ARN in the same `main.tf` file.

This is my terraform `main.tf`

```
variable "ENV" {}
variable "TAGS" {}

// SECRET MANAGER
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "service_name_sm" {
  name = "service-name-sm-test"
  tags = var.TAGS
}

// POLICY
resource "aws_iam_policy" "service_name_policy" {
  name = "${var.service_name_policy_name}-${var.ENV}"
  path = "/"
  policy = templatefile(
    "${path.module}/templates/${var.service_name_policy_name}.tmpl", {
      secrets_manager_arn = resource.aws_secretsmanager_secret.service_name_sm.arn
  })
}
```

In the policy I create, I want to use the ARN of the aws_secretsmanager_secret resource I create.

When I run, `terraform validate` I get an error:

```
A managed resource "resource" "aws_secretsmanager_secret" has not been
declared in service_name.
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Not completely sure, but if I understand the documentation at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/secretsmanager_secret correctly, you are looking for `resource.aws_secretsmanager_secret.service_name_sm.kms_key_id`

Comment: tried it, does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to prefix the things with `resource.`. You have to reference it like this `aws_secretsmanager_secret.service_name_sm`.

```
policy = templatefile(
  "${path.module}/templates/${var.service_name_policy_name}.tmpl", {
    secrets_manager_arn = aws_secretsmanager_secret.service_name_sm.arn
})
```